# Maven build fails with obscure message after changing dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am relatively new to `Maven`.  I changed a library my project is using to a newer version.  I only installed it in the local repository (`~/.m2`), not in our `artifactory`:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./Apis_Google_Maps-3.8.1.jar -DgroupId=com.github.branflake2267 -DartifactId=gwt-maps-api -Dversion=3.10.0-alpha-6 -Dpackaging=jar`

Then I changed my `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- Google Maps (use recompiled gwt 2.2 jar) -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt-google-maps-v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-google-maps-v3-gwt22</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.branflake2267</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maps-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

And the error message is:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0:compile (default) on project <myproject>

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException
```

Am I missing something?  Maven is not reporting any Java compilation errors and I do not think I have Java any (as per my IDE), so I think the build problem is within Maven.

The most confusing thing to me is that this error message I am getting indicates nothing even remotely related to the change I made.

Comment: can you run maven with -e flag. It will give detail log of the exceptions.

Comment: Also can you please specify the exact command which is giving this error?